# Array of Coordinates

Tags: javascript

I have an array of coordinates in javascript declared as `path1 = new Array();` with no size. I will just push the coordinates send from my android application and use this array as a path for my polyline.

Now my question is, is there a limit on how many elements in an array?

I try to track my gps and the first few coordinates works fine. I can see my polyline. But suddenly the polyline will disappear.

Any help will be appreciated. Sorry for my bad english.

```
enter code herefunction path(sender,latitude,longitude,speed,id,path,color,plength){
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
var polyPath = polyArray(path);
createPoly(polyPath,color);
createMarker(latlng,sender,speed,plength);
}
function polyArray(path){
var array = path.split(',');
var path1 =new Array();
for(var i=0;i<=array.length;i=i+2){
var coordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(array[i],array[i+1]);
path1.push(coordinates);
}
return path1;
} 
function createPoly(path,color){
var polyOptions = {
path:path,
strokeColor: color,
strokeOpacity: 1.0,
strokeWeight: 1
};
poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
poly.setMap(map);
}
function createMarker(latlng,sender,speed,plength){
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: latlng,
map: map
});
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:sender + "\n" + speed + "m/s"});
infowindow.open(map, marker);
markers.push(marker);
for(var i=0;i<markers.length-plength;i++)
markers[i].setMap(null);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Off-topic: if you don't set the size, `[]` is faster than `new Array()`. And always declare your variables using `var`.

Comment: Show the code you have so far. From your description, nobody can tell what's going wrong.

Comment: I just edited my question and added my code Olaf Dietsche.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *only* create arrays of less than `2^32 = 4.294.967.296` entries:

```
new Array(4294967295) // works
```

but

```
new Array(4294967296) // RangeError: invalid array length
```

This behavior is defined in the [spec](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_15.htm#Section_15.4):

> Every Array object has a length property whose value is always a
>   nonnegative integer less than 2^32

Comment: I am using gooogle chrome.

Comment: I have an array of coordinates but when I try to add one more element into the array I cannot see the polyline.Seems like it reached its limit.

Comment: @user3157712 Which is that limit? Is it reasonable?

Comment: @Oriol : limit for array size is `2^32 - 1` which is `4294967295`

Comment: What do you mean reasonable?

Comment: @user3157712 I mean if it is `2^32` or is something like `100`

Comment: no its just bunch of latitude and longitude.10.300580,
123.896375, for example. I use split method to convert it to javascript array. It has 48 elements. If I add 2 more entries as latitude and longitude the polyline will no longer appear..

Comment: @user3157712 Then the problem isn't the number of entries. Check your console for errors.

Comment: I store the coordinates in database as string. Then, I fetched and split to make it an array. Then I can see the polyline if there are less than 48 entries. More than that the polyline will disappear. But when I checked the database It has the string. The problem is in the array.

Comment: @user3157712 No, I mean browser's console. To open it, press Ctrl+Shift+J on Chrome, or Ctrl+Shift+K on Firefox

Comment: @Oriol I just restarted my pc.After several hours I turned it on and it works fine.I dont know what is goind on. Anyway thank you for you help. Thank you for sharing your expertise..Thumbs up!